# UIButton not responsive while scrolling

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I have a subview with a UIButton added to a UIScrollView.

The button is working perfectly as long as the user isn't scrolling.
If the UIScrollView is still scrolling when the user clicks on the button, it just stops the scrolling instead(like if a row had been clicked).

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What are you doing on click of button ?

Comment: @franknirania just triggering a method. It is being triggered when the UIScrollView isn't scrolling and the user clicks though.

Comment: My guess is someone has posted a similar question here - why not poke around? I'm going to guess the answer is to going use a gesture recognizer added to the scrollView, or perhaps a view that intercepts touches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure this really is the behavior you want - iOS users are used to scrolling views and touching to stop them with a tap without triggering button presses. Non-standard behavior (even when you think its *better* then the standard behavior) can be confusing to users used to how things work in other iOS apps - it can violate their [mental model](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/mental-models.html). Ok, note of caution over.

So how do you fix this? `UIScrollView` delays sending touch events until it knows if those touches are scroll events. You problem is a user tapping *is* a scroll event when the `UIScrollView` is moving. Two possible solutions:

1. Stop the `UIScrollView` from delaying any touch events it gets. You can set any scroll views `delaysContentTouches` to `NO`, which will stop the delaying action and should allow your buttons to be tapped while scrolling. You can read about it in the [`UIScrollView` class documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html). You will also want to read up on `canCancelContentTouches` there as well.
2. Subclass the `UIScrollView` to add your own logic about where touch events should go. [Here is a blog post that discusses how to do this](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/detect-single-tap-in-uiscrollview.html).